# How to detect simultaneous swipe and touch-ended

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe, gesture

Is it possible to detect direction of swipe and simultaneously detect release of finger from screen?  When I use gesture recognizer from Object library, it works only swipe or only touchesEnded, but not simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `cancelsTouchesInView` to NO on your swipe gesture recognizer. If you're working from interface builder, it's the `Canceled in View` checkbox.